# Android. Передача JSON на сервер методом POST

Tags: json, post

Добрый день. 
Пытаюсь передать данные JSON на сервер. За основу взял [Вот эту статью](http://dajver.blogspot.ru/2013/02/json.html). 
Код который применяет автор:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    try {
                            //создаем запрос на сервер
                            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
                            //он у нас будет посылать post запрос
                            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                            //будем передавать два параметра
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                            //передаем параметры из наших текстбоксов
                            //лоигн
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login.getText().toString()));
                            //пароль
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass.getText().toString()));
                            //собераем их вместе и посылаем на сервер
                            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            //получаем ответ от сервера
                            String response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
                            //посылаем на вторую активность полученные параметры
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                            //то что куда мы будем передавать и что, putExtra(куда, что);
                            intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.JsonURL, response.toString());
                            startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
                    }
                    return null;
            }
```

Моя проблема: Код написан на "устаревшем" apache.http.client.
 Я перевел сам POST запрос на  HttpURLConnection, но не могу разобраться с 
`List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login.getText().toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass.getText().toString()));`

Как можно реализовать передачу "login" и "pass" используя HttpURLConnection, чтобы файл.php на сервере получил значения JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Если ты хочешь именно использовать HttpURLConnection [тут](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) есть нормальный пример. Но лучше посмотри в сторону библиотеки [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), она очень проста в использовании.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрел пример и не смог найти то место, где я могу задать имя переменной login или pass.

Comment: Он задает параметры в переменной String urlParameters. В твоем случае должно быть что то такое.
String utlParameters = "login=" + login.getText().toString() + "&pass=" + pass.getText().toString().

Comment: Попробовал использовать вот такой метод: String urlParameters = "anton={\"login\":\"123\",\"password\":\"321\"}"; con.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream dStream = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dStream, "utf-8"));

                writer.write(urlParameters);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close(); нет изменений. На сервере смотрю логи - в теле POST запроса пусто, но параметры POST принимаются.